# Equals method is not working for two same object

Tags: java, collections, set, equals, hashset

I have written a code to find unique Images. Two images are equal if they have the same name (even if the extension is different) and the size is equal (width * length).
But It's failing to find unique images.
Even after overriding the equals method, the HashSet method is failing to identify two similar objects.

```
    import java.util.*;

    class UniqueImages {
    public static class Image {
    private String filename;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Image(String filename, int width, int height) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((filename == null) ? 0 : filename.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + height;
        result = prime * result + width;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Two Images are considered equal if they have
     * the same filename (without the extension), and the
     * same number of pixels.
     * Thus, flag.jpg with width=60 height=40 is
     * equal to flag.gif with width=40 and height=60
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Image o = (Image)other;
        if (filename == null || o.filename == null)
            return false;
        String[] components = filename.split("\\.");
        String[] ocomponents = o.filename.split("\\.");
        return components[0].equals(ocomponents[0]) && 
            width * height == o.width * o.height;
      }

        public String toString() {
           return "Image: filename=" + filename + " Size=" + width*height;
      }
    }

    public static void printImages(Set<Image> images) {
        for(Image image: images) {
           System.out.println(image);
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Image[] images = {new Image("flag.jpg", 40, 60),
                      new Image("flag.gif", 40, 60),
                      new Image("smile.gif", 100, 200),
                      new Image("smile.gif", 50, 400),
                      new Image("other.jpg", 40, 60),
                      new Image("lenna.jpg", 512, 512),
                      new Image("Lenna.jpg", 512, 512)};
    
          Set<Image> set = new HashSet<Image>(Arrays.asList(images));
          UniqueImages.printImages(set);
        }
      }
```

Comment: You might want to make the name comparison case-insensitive. Besides, should a 50x400 image be considered the same as a 100x200 image? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: the total size of both is the same that's why I am considering it as same.

Comment: Your hashCode() is inconsistent with equals(). You should make the hashCode follow the same rules as equals, which means ignoring the filename extension.

Comment: You could let your IDE generate `equals` and `hashCode` for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two images having the same total size are considered equal by your `equals()` method (even if they don't have the same `width` and `height`), they should also have the same `hashCode()`.

But that's not the only issue. You should also change `hashCode()` to ignore the file name suffixes, in order for it to fit the implementation of `equals()`.

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((filename == null) ? 0 : filename.split("\\.")[0].hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (height * width);
    return result;
}
```

With these two changes, the `HashSet` will eliminate two duplicates, resulting in:

```
Image: filename=smile.gif Size=20000
Image: filename=flag.jpg Size=2400
Image: filename=lenna.jpg Size=262144
Image: filename=other.jpg Size=2400
Image: filename=Lenna.jpg Size=262144
```

Comment: it may be worth to select a substring _before_ the last dot in the filename instead of the prefix _before_ the first dot.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Possibly. The important thing is that the `hashCode()` implementation conforms with the `equals()` implementation, which is what I did.

Comment: Agree, this is quite an exotic case of considering image files _equal_ :)

Answer (score 0):

Eran already gave the answer. However, I would like to highlight the issues in your `.equals()` implementation. Your cast is not safe. Here's how I would write it (using the template given in Bloch's *Effective Java*):

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if(!(o instance of Image)) {
        return false;
    }
    Image o = (Image)other;
    if (filename == null || o.filename == null)
        return false;
    String[] components = filename.split("\\.");
    String[] ocomponents = o.filename.split("\\.");
    return components[0].equals(ocomponents[0]) && 
        width * height == o.width * o.height;
}
```